# Parent-child relation with Rc/RefCell not working

Tags: rust

I just started with rust and am trying to implement a struct that has a parent and child.

The function `set_child` updates the child of the current `X` and sets the child's parent to be the current `X`, but I'm encountering many problems that I have a very rough understanding of and can't fix.

Any help is appreciated :)

### main.rs

```
use std::{rc::Rc, cell::RefCell, borrow::BorrowMut};

struct X {
    parent: Option<Rc<RefCell<X>>>,
    child: Option<Rc<RefCell<X>>>,
    value: i32,
}

impl X {
    fn new() -> Self {
        X {
            parent: None,
            child: None,
            value: 10
        }
    }

    fn set_child(&self, obj: Rc<RefCell<X>>) {
        self.borrow_mut().child = Some(obj); 

        let &mut child = match self.child {
            Some(x) => x.borrow_mut(),
            None => todo!()
        };

        // no field `parent` on type `Rc<RefCell<X>>`
        // and there is an error that says I cannot pass `self`
        // it has to be a `Rc<RefCell<X>>`
        child.parent = self;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're starting out in Rust, anything with `Rc` and `RefCell` is a terrible place to find yourself. It's possible to model these complex multi-directional relationships in Rust, but it's a more advanced feature, and as a beginner you should stick to simple hierarchical (single-ownership) data. See [Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/), for instance.

Comment: Your code is wrong in so many ways. [Here's a good implementation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b28691603cedee11a43936c05b3aa31f).

Comment: In particular, `let &mut child = ...` is not what you want, it kind of does the opposite. You want `let child = ...` or, if you want to annotate `child` with a type, `let chid: &mut X = ...`. (But it won't compile because `borrow_mut()` doesn't actually return a reference, but a proxy type that can hand out a reference.)